# Retrofit 2 Upload Image Multiple

Tags: android, image, retrofit, retrofit2

```
        "gallery": [
            {
                "galleryId": 113,
                "type": "image",
                "filename": "image_599bbbb569b78.png"
            },
            {
                "galleryId": 114,
                "type": "image",
                "filename": "image_599bbdd023a31.png"
            }
        ],
        "likeCount": 2,
```

I don't know how to use retrofit 2 to upload image like this. can someone please share example. 
i can use retrofit2 upload in one-to-one field but one-to-many i don't know how to use.

Comment: You want to upload a String? ;-) It looks like that you have a gallery somewhere and needs to point to the file.

Comment: no no no  in an example after upload image. i want to upload image to server

Comment: gallery": [],   this field gallery before upload. i don't know how to add. my api have more field to add.  In other field i have no probelm but field gallery i don't know how to add.

Comment: clear it if you want to upload from your device

Comment: no no no. above code  is json after complete process. but i can't add data in field gallery. that above code is a future when you complete all process

Answer (score 0):

```
Call<AnnouncementHeaderModel> announcement_add(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] filename
        ,@Part MultipartBody.Part[] type
        ,@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap);
```

I solved my problem like this.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
To upload data in below json format:

```
    {
  "gallery": [
            {
                "galleryId": 113,
                "type": "image",
                "filename": "image_599bbbb569b78.png"
            },
            {
                "galleryId": 114,
                "type": "image",
                "filename": "image_599bbdd023a31.png"
            }
        ],
   "likeCount": 2
}
```

you have to fill data in below POJO and send to retrofit body

```
   import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class UploadGallery {

    @SerializedName("gallery")
    @Expose
    private List<Gallery> gallery = null;
    @SerializedName("likeCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer likeCount;

    public List<Gallery> getGallery() {
    return gallery;
    }

    public void setGallery(List<Gallery> gallery) {
    this.gallery = gallery;
    }

    public Integer getLikeCount() {
    return likeCount;
    }

    public void setLikeCount(Integer likeCount) {
    this.likeCount = likeCount;
    }

    public class Gallery {

    @SerializedName("galleryId")
    @Expose
    private Integer galleryId;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("filename")
    @Expose
    private String filename;

    public Integer getGalleryId() {
    return galleryId;
    }

    public void setGalleryId(Integer galleryId) {
    this.galleryId = galleryId;
    }

    public String getType() {
    return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    }

    }
}
```

This will create a list of objects of gallery just like you want to send. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: List<MultipartBody.Part> files   if i use my code  that files is store data in my gallery field. am i correct?

Comment: but i think. my gallery[]type  how to add string in this field. my gallery[]id my server is create. i don't seem how to add this field. i see this code have upload image only. am i correct ?

Comment: so you are saying you need to add some field in the above json and don't know how to add it using retrofit

Comment: If this is the case then you can use Gson library retrofit has nothing to do with your response it just give you back what ever server has for you and take whatever you want to send to server. let me know if i am pointing you correct here so that i can update my answer with relevant code.

Comment: sorry to late comment. my case have more field than my topic. other field is one-to-one i can use retrofit to add data but i have one problem is field gallery. this field is one-to-many. i don't know how to add data in this field. if gallery don't have upload image. i have no problem.i can send array but this field have to upload image and add type of file. my postman  http://www.mx7.com/view2/A4xB79QDXLTSxYNo

Comment: your answer is can use in field one-to-one and your link is use one-to-one. this is my parameter. http://www.mx7.com/view2/A4xEkJSBBPSRVmSS

Comment: i have edited my answer hope this solves your problem

Comment: i understand you. my POJO same you. but  if i add data in model. field filename can upload photo or not. i can post Body not use  Multipart yes or no ?

Comment: this day. i use your answer but image not upload. i don't know api incorrect or code in correct